# Bad redirection of Mattermost docker behind reverse proxy apache2

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mattermost

I am trying to install the docker version of Mattermost on my Ubuntu 14.04 with apache2 version 2.4.7.

Here is the configuration of `mattermost-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.my.website.fr
        ServerAlias website.fr
        DocumentRoot /home/www/www-website
  [...]
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    RewriteEngine  on

    ProxyPass /mattermost http://localhost:8083
    ProxyPassReverse /mattermost http://localhost:8083

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/v[0-9]+/(users/)?websocket [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8083%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

    <Location /home/www/www-soft/mattermost>
      Require all granted
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8083/
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8083/
    </Location>
[...]
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The website is accessible but nothing appears on the page, because I got such error messages (one example among several others of the same form):
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://www.my.website.fr/static/main.9e27a2872d73987ea8ec.css`

Instead of trying to access the file at:

`https://www.my.website.fr/mattermost/static/main.9e27a2872d73987ea8ec.css` (which exists, I tested)

(I replaced my website domain by "my.website.fr")

Is there any obvious reason why the apache proxy is not redirecting correctly with the `/mattermost` prefix ? Am I missing something ?

The dedicated page in Mattermost documentation didn't help me much resolving this (https://docs.mattermost.com/install/config-apache2.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From apache documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location

> The  directive limits the scope of the enclosed directives
> by URL.

Which means you need to change:

```
<Location /home/www/www-soft/mattermost>
  Require all granted
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8083/
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8083/
</Location>
```

to

```
<Location /mattermost>
  Require all granted
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8083/
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8083/
</Location>
```

Because your document root is set to

```
DocumentRoot /home/www/www-website
```

You're also using proxypass to handle requests to the same path

```
ProxyPass /mattermost http://localhost:8083
ProxyPassReverse /mattermost http://localhost:8083
```

You need to chose which solution you want to implement: both might not work well together.

At last, you're also using

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

which I'm not sure it's needed/working as you think: please refer to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost to find out if it's realy required in your environment.